# Truncated If Statement C++ (Turning letters to numbers)

Tags: c++, if-statement, statements, truncated

I am trying to change a series of letters into numbers with C++ and have started by making this code.

However, it appears that the math that calculates the digit1 variable is never getting executed.

Any thoughts?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int qtyofnumbers, num, digit1, counter;
    char letters, upperlower;

    cout << "Enter a letter: ";
    cin >> letters;

    for (counter = 0; counter < 8; counter++)
    {
        if (counter == 3)
            cout << "-";

        num = static_cast<int>(letters) - static_cast<int>('A');

        if (0 <= num && num < 26)
            digit1 = (num / 3) + 2;

        if (((num / 3 == 6 ) || (num / 3 == 7)) && (num % 3 == 0))
            digit1 = digit1-1;

        if (digit1 > 9)
            digit1 = 9;    

        cin >> letters;
    }

    cout << digit1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `{` and `}` !!!

Comment: Please indent your code properly before asking for help. It's hard to read it as it is.

Comment: did u step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: @jtbandes, thanks that did it. Should be more organized..thanks!

Comment: Do your first two `if`s cover all possible values of `num` that your program can encounter? If not, `digit1` will be used uninitialised in the third `if`, and that's UB through and through. I _guess_ they cover all values, but still.

Comment: show us sample input and expected output

Comment: Also, you might like to know that you can declare variables in a `for` statement (and soon in C++17, apparently, `if` and `switch`) and therefore need not declare `count` at function scope. _Also_, get out of the habit of postincrementing things when you don't need the pre-incremented value. I have no idea why that is so many people's default. It can pointlessly slow down your code once you start using iterators, etc.

Comment: @underscore_d Nice post-increment rant. :) I 100% agree.

Comment: sadly its K&R's standard for for loops, we will always be stuck with it

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem is in your input. Are you entering capital letters or lowercase letters? Their [ASCII codes](http://www.asciitable.com/) are different. So, you probably want to change the code from

```
num= static_cast<int>(letters)-static_cast<int>('A');
```

to something like

```
if (num >= 'a')
    num = letters - 'a';
else
    num = letters - 'A';
```

Also, as mentioned by @jtbandes, use the curly braces `{` and `}`. Whitespace does not determine scope in C++. Even if it's for only one line of code after your if-statement, it'll save you headaches in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Is the static cast necessary? I recommend using a string stream or just traversing the string character by character using .at() and relying on the ascii values for conversion. http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html.